# Testing proportion differences between conditions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion

I've asked 10 people to choose between A and B in 3 different conditions and 5 times per condition (resulting in 5 data points per person for condition 1, 5 data points per person for condition 2 and 5 data points per person for condition 3).

My question is whether the proportion of A choices differs between conditions. To start, I'm going to use a chi-squared test (or rather a Fisher's exact test) using only the data from each participant's first response for each condition.

However, I'd also like to test whether the proportion of A choices differs between conditions using the full data set. Can I gather all A responses for each condition and then run a chi-squared test, even though there are 5 data points per participant per condition? Or should I use something else? (Perhaps a mixed model with participant ID as a random factor?)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to account for the structure of your experiment (repeated measures -> nonindependent observations) you could run a GLMM assuming a binomial error distribution. This is also known as a logistic regression.

The model would follow as:

prob(A) ~ condition + (1 | participantID)

Where the participant ID is modeled as a random intercept.

In R: (assuming your data is long and tidy)

library(lme4)

mod1 <- glmer(cbind(A, B) ~ condition + (1 | participantID),
family = binomial(link = "logit"),
data = yourdata

summary(mod1)

Will print the model coefficients as odds ratios. You'll see an intercept, condition 2, and condition 3. The coefficients for each of the condition terms are the difference from condition 1 (the intercept).

Note that the interpretation of this model is slightly different from the Fisher test approach. For example, a significant positive effect of condition 2 would be interpreted as "condition 2 significantly increased the probability of selecting A over B.